# Flash builder project import error

Tags: flash-builder

I am trying to import a project in Flash builder. I am using the option, import existing project. I get the error "path of the project must have only one segment".

Can some one help me resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

This problem can also occur if the eclipse workspace is of the same folder as the root of the project.   The problem can be resolved by setting the workspace one folder level higher.

Comment: Thank you very much! This resolved my problem with the message: "Invalid project description".

Answer (score 0):

I believe this refers to the project name being invalid, which can occur when 3rd party tools generate Eclipse projects.

Within the project you are attempting to import, open the ".project" file located at the root of the project.

Assure the name of the project is a simple identifier without path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>example</name>
```

If this does not resolve you issue, please post the contents of your .project file.